# Angular - update controller data from another controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm just starting to use AngularJS.

I have a simple CRUD app which communicates to REST api. I have two controllers which control my `Projects` data and `Tasks` data respectfully. On the backend Tasks are liked by foreign key to the parent Project. So when I delete a `Project` the associated `Tasks` are also deleted (this is the functionality I want right now).

So everything works except that when I delete a Project I want to reload the Tasks list. Basically after `ConcernService.del('projects/', item)` is called I want the Tasks list to be refreshed from the API. I know this should be handled via the `ConcernsService`, but I'm not sure of the best way.

```
// --- CONCERNS FACTORY --- //
concernsApp.factory('ConcernService', function ($http, $q) {
    var api_url = "/path/to/api/";

    var ConcernService = {
        list: function (items_url) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http({method: 'GET', url: api_url + items_url}).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    defer.resolve(data);
                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    defer.reject(status);
                });
            return defer.promise;
        },
        del: function(item_url, obj) {
            return $http.delete(api_url + item_url + obj.id + '/');
        },
    };
    return ConcernService;
});


// --- PROJECTS CONTROLLER --- //
concernsApp.controller('ProjectsCtrl', function ($scope, $http, ConcernService) {
    // get all projects
    $scope.projects = ConcernService.list('projects/');

    // assign the delete method to the scope
    $scope.deleteItem = function(item) {
        ConcernService.del('projects/', item).then(function(){
            // reload projects
            $scope.projects = ConcernService.list('projects/');
        });
    };
});


// --- TASKS CONTROLLER --- //
concernsApp.controller('TasksCtrl', function ($scope, $http, ConcernService) {
    // get all tasks
    $scope.tasks = ConcernService.list('tasks/');

    // assign the delete method to the scope
    $scope.deleteItem = function(item) {
        ConcernService.del('tasks/', item).then(function(){
            // reload projects
            $scope.tasks = ConcernService.list('tasks/');
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: really need call to API to reload all data each time? How about working with local arrays and splicing/pushing after delete/add/update request made? Fairly easy to implement

Comment: My concern there is that the array may become out of sync with what is actually happening in the db. For example if I delete the item from the array but it doesn't actually get deleted in the db. Is this an issue I should be concerned with?

Comment: also, I am building this app and learning. I would like to know *how* to answer my question, even if I re-factor to use in-memory data models in the future.

Comment: do it in success of request to db. Up to you. If get more subsets means more db calls. Personally since appears you have full task list, and not loading tasks by specific project could merge local data so tasks are already children of projects in main project array. Removing project from local data would also remove it's chidren

Comment: Yes, I see the logic in that approach. As I say, though, I do not need much complexity at the moment and I'm happy with the api calls. If I treat an array as my projects/models I run the risk of users interacting with stale data. So, I would like to keep it simple for now, which would mean an extra API call on delete. Any suggestions on how to solve my original question?

Comment: not sure how to answer question actually, the way you have disconnected tasks from projects and isolated how they are retrieved. Both are bound to API calls and no local data used

Comment: Right. I have the controllers separated as I anticipate wanting to do stuff with projects or tasks independently from one another, but of course the data itself has a relationship. I'm guess there is some preferred mechanism for dealing with this, but I'm not sure what it is...

Comment: using API for everything will make it complex. Resolve tasks call with a local array stored in service , splice that is easier than what you are trying to do

Comment: Yep - I see that, and I think that is where I will end up. I think my solution now will be to roll projects and tasks into a single controller, which will mitigate the need for cross controller talk.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a generic service, you could have a service that is more specific to your project and that service could contains the model (projects and tasks). When it would update internally, the watchers from each controller would trigger and update their data.

When you want to share the model between controllers, the model should be kept in a service and you should use getter and setter to access it.

This acticle use an older version of Angular, but it will explain you how to use the service as your model.

http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-1-architecture/